# Apache Drill: Create Table Error While Selecting from Json Data

Tags: json, apache, hadoop, apache-drill, mapr

Below command is working fine.

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(`ts`,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') 
FROM dfs.tmp`/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json
```

But when I am trying to create a table from select statement then it is giving an error. Below are the ones I tried

```
ALTER SESSION SET `store.format`='json';
use dfs;

CREATE TABLE by_yr (gen_date)  AS SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(`ts`,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') FROM dfs.`/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json` LIMIT 100;

**Error:**
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 8. Was expecting one of: "." ... "[" ... SQL Query use dfs; ^ CREATE TABLE by_yr (gen_date) AS SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(`ts`,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') FROM dfs.`/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json` LIMIT 100 [Error Id: 81cbe394-b3c6-4c34-80ad-83325f748ae1 on iot3:31010]

use dfs.tmp;

CREATE TABLE by_yr (gen_date)  AS SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(`ts`,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') FROM dfs.tmp`/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json` LIMIT 100;

**Error:**
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: "." ... "[" ... SQL Query use dfs.tmp; ^ SELECT COLUMNS[0], COLUMNS[1] from dfs.tmp.`/mapr/my.cluster.com/donuts.json` [Error Id: 5e9d1d20-a804-4d09-8b69-d76b3c009647 on iot2:31010]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting single quotes around the path such as:

```
ALTER SESSION SET store.format='json'; use dfs;

CREATE TABLE by_yr (gen_date) AS 
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(ts,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') 
FROM dfs.'/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json' LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Still its not working. Error:org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 38. Was expecting one of: ... "UESCAPE" ... SQL Query ALTER SESSION SET store.format='json'; ^ use dfs; CREATE TABLE by_yr (gen_date) AS SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(ts,'yyyyMMddHHmmss') FROM dfs.'/mapr/my.cluster.com/hive/cpf_sales.json' LIMIT 100

Answer (score 0):

This is working

CREATE TABLE myHDFS.testdata.`/xuser/sample2.json` AS SELECT * FROM myHDFS.testdata.`sample.json`

with storage configuration

"testdata": {
  "location": "/dir/data/test",
  "writable": true,
  "defaultInputFormat": "json"
},